# Loop through a string to find text between character sets

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to create a JavaScript function which would extract pre-defined variables from a string. Within the string, these variables will be nested within the "<>" character set.

**For example:** 
the string which is typed by the user could be: `I am <me> , my age is <myage>`
which would then render the text: `I am Joe Bloggs , my age is 21` (given the two user defined variables 'me' and 'myage')

I have begun to use the split funciton, but this is not going well.

```
function parse_String(theString) {
var varSplit = theString.split("<");
    };
```

Is there an elegant solution, either using javascript or RegEx?

Comment: Use the string `.replace()` method with a regex search pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var result = theString.substring(theString.indexOf('<')+1, theString.indexOf('>'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to look for a 'templating' function. If you format the initial string like this `'I am {0}, my age is {1}'`, you could use this method:

```
function stringFormat() {
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
   return this.replace(/(\{\d+\})/g, function(a) {
            return args[ +(a.split(/[{}]/)[1]) || 0 ];
          });
};
// usage
stringFormat.call('I am {0}, my age is {1}','Joe Bloggs','21');
//=> I am Joe Bloggs, my age is 21
```

You could add the method to `String.prototype`:

```
String.prototype.Format = stringFormat;
// usage
'I am {0}, my age is {1}'.Format('Joe Bloggs','21');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do a replace function. I assume you want to replace the predifined places with your own variables.

```
function parse(string, data) {
     $.each(data, function (v, k) {
         string = string.replace('<'+k+'>', v);
     });
     return string;
}
```

Example

```
 parse("<me> is <age> years old", {me:'Han', age:22});
```

output: `Han is 22 years old`